# Can someone explain what the wireless data phone is on the TCP/IP layer?

Tags: wireless, tcp

Can someone explain to me if a wireless phone is a device, just like a computer, that's connected to a huge wireless router called the Verizon network, or another 192.168.x.x device when it picks up a local wireless open network? Does it have an IP address that I can obtain e.g. whatismyip.com online somehow when it's connected to the 4G network on Verizon? I don't know if this is the right place to ask but I'm a long-time Java developer and enterprise architect and I'm studying TCP/IP for messaging and it's reliability. I have more questions now that relate to mobile phones and that's the reason for my understanding of the phone as a network device. MAC address? IP number?

Any responses are well appreciated.

Thanks,

David L. Whitehurst, CEO CI Wise Inc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4G mobile phones are end-devices like PCs; you can get a 4G card for a PC. The phones get IP addresses, and, most likely, the 4G phone will get an IPv6 address, and, on some carriers, and IPv4 address. There is usually somewhere in the phone information where you can find the carrier assigned IP address(es), and those addresses will probably (for IPv4) differ from what a web site tells you your IPv4 address is because most of the mobile carriers use CGN.

For programming questions (with many network-savvy programmers), you need to ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: For DATA, yes. *Voice* doesn't (normally) run over IP.

Comment: Right, voice is still primarily on 3G (even on 4G phones) but that is changing slowly in the U.S, but more rapidly in other countries.

Comment: Specifically, can one figure out what his IP is on the phone when it's using it's subscriber data plan and not a local wireless? How?

Comment: That depends on the phone model. I can go into my phone and pull that up on one of the information screens, but other phones I have do it very differently. Every phone I have had (and they have been many) has had this information somewhere to view.

Comment: I found an app for my Samsung phone called Fing and it finds everything on the wireless the phone is connected to. I just found all of the 192.168.2.x devices on my Belkin. Thanks everyone for comments.